# Flutter Firebase Database wrong timestamp order

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I'm trying to set timestamp into firebase realtime database but when I retrieve, not ordering by timestamp.
I did like so.

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('path').push().set({
      'timestamp': ServerValue.timestamp
    });
```

This is the node

[image]

Then I retrieve like so.

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('path').orderByChild('timestamp').once().then((snap) {
            print(snap.value);
          });
```

but output is this

```
{-LJhyfmrWVDD2ZgJdfMR: {timestamp: 1534074731794}, -LJhyWVi6LddGwVye48K: {timestamp: 1534074689667}, -LJhzDlvEMunxBpRmTkI: {timestamp: 1534074875091}
```

Those are not ordered by timestamp.
Am I missing something? 
Otherwise is this firebase error or flutter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data is retrieved in the right order into a `DataSnapshot`. But when you call `snap.value` the information from the snapshot has to be converted into a `Map<String, Object>`, which not longer can hold information about the order of the child nodes.

To maintain the order, you have to process the child nodes from the `DataSnapshot` with a loop. I'm not an expert in Flutter (at all), but I can't quickly find a way to do this for a value event. So you might want to instead listen for `.childAdded`:

```
   FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child('path')
        .orderByChild('timestamp')
        .onChildAdded
        .listen((Event event) {
      print(event.snapshot.value);
    })
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It worked perfectly! If I used `DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch`, is it going to work as well? Type is int but document says milliseconds since 1970. So I guess it works but I just want to make sure.