# flutter firebase realtime database: how to get the result of orderByValue as a List<String>?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I keep list of hashtags and their appearance in realtime db.

[image]

And I want to make a service class with a function to retrieve hashtags as a List in descending order of appearance. So below is the preferred result.

```
List<String> expHashList = [개발자, 인사담당자, VC, 작가, 경영자];
List<String> topicList = [커리어, 채용, 이직, 리더십, 조직문화];
```

I tried below but it returns empty list(`[]`).

```
class HashtagService {
  static final HashtagService _instance = HashtagService._internal();
  factory HashtagService() => _instance;

  late final DatabaseReference _database;

  HashtagService._internal() {
    _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('/hashtags');
  }

  List<String> getSuggestion(String type) {
    if (type == 'exp') {
      var query = _database.child('expHash').orderByValue().limitToLast(10);
      return FirebaseList(query: query).cast<String>();
    } else {
      var query = _database.child('topic').orderByValue().limitToLast(10);
      return FirebaseList(query: query).cast<String>();
    }
  }
}
```

This is second approach but I can't figure out type casting and sort compare function to work correctly. And this version returns Future<List> instead.

```
  Future<List<String>> getSuggestion() async {
    return await _database.child('expHash').get().then((snapshot) {
      Map<String, int> map = snapshot.value;   // type error -> <dynamic, dynamic>
      List<String> hashtagList = map.keys.toList();   
      hashtagList.sort((k1, k2) => map[k1]! > map[k2]! ? 1 : -1);   // is this right?
      return hashtagList;
    });
  }
```

What's the best way to get the result of orderByValue(or orderByKey or orderByChild) as a List or List?

---

**EDIT(Answer)**

```
List<String?> _resultList = [];

var query = _database.child('topic').orderByValue().limitToLast(10);
query.onChildAdded.listen((Event event) {
    _resultList.add(event.snapshot.key);
});
return await query.get().then((snapshot) {return _resultList;});
```

But this returns `Future<List<String>>` instead. So I had to use FutureBuilder to process output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In recent versions of the FlutterFire library for Firebase you should be able to use `snapshot.value.values` to get an ordered list of the result snapshots of a query.

If that is not working, the previous approach is either [Flutter: Firebase Real-Time database orderByChild has no impact on query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333194/flutter-firebase-real-time-database-orderbychild-has-no-impact-on-query-result/61333575#61333575) or [Flutter Firebase Database wrong timestamp order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808719/flutter-firebase-database-wrong-timestamp-order/51811808#51811808) or

Comment: Future<DataSnapshot> getSuggestion(String type) {
    return _database.child('expHash').orderByValue().limitToLast(10).get();
}

var snapshot = await _hashtagService.getSuggestion(widget.type);
_suggestionList = snapshot.value.keys.toList();
print(_suggestionList);

result: [작가, 인사담당자, VC, 개발자, 경영자] <= not ordered unfortunately.

Comment: I've seen your comments in those links (that's why I tried FirebaseList) but event.snapshot.value returned String? instead of String. So when I tried to display result with Text() it returned error.

Comment: On comment #1: as said, you need `snapshot.value.values`, not `snapshot.value.keys`. This is the PR where it was fixed: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/5765/files, for example: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/5765/files#diff-418793b2ebfd03035fe29613a585498e8e9bf01b13cbb8692c2e1ccf669c1ffaR42-R44

Comment: snapshot.value.values.toList(); returns [2, 3, 2, 5, 0]. I need hashtags not appearance. (btw they are not ordered either)